# Removing the usage of fromJust

Tags: haskell, refactoring, option-type

Say, I have some code like this:

```
data Record = Record {
  validate :: Maybe Bool,
  mobile :: Text
}

someFunction :: Monad m => m ()
someFunction = do
  (record :: Maybe Record) <- getRecord
  let hasValidated = join $ validate <$> record
  case hasValidated of
     Just True -> do
        sendSMS (mobile $ fromJust record)
     _ -> return ()
```

Now when `hasValidate` has some value of `Just _`, I can know for sure
that `record` isn't `Nothing`. Is there a way to remove `fromJust`
without using multiple case or without changing the signature of
`sendSMS` function.

Note that the above code is a simplistic scenario of my
codebase.

Comment: I think this doesn't typecheck. `hasValidated` has type `Maybe (Maybe Bool)`, not `Maybe Bool`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give the boolean to `guard`:

```
someFunction = do
    mrecord <- getRecord
    let hasValidated = mrecord >>= validate
    case hasValidated >>= guard >> mrecord of
        Just record -> do
            sendSMS (mobile record)
        _ -> return ()
```

This is a tidy solution, though as Daniel Wagner points out it performs at least one redundant check (two if we compare it with [Reid Barton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42397237/2751851)). Just for fun, here is a golfed version of [Daniel Wagner's first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42397237/2751851):

```
someFunction = do
    mrecord <- getRecord
    case mrecord >>= liftA2 fmap (,) validate of
        Just (record, True) -> do
            sendSMS (mobile record)
        _ -> return ()
```

Comment: This will check `mrecord` for `Nothing`ness twice.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yup, this just squeezes the redundant check into a syntactically convenient form. It is a lazy (not in the technical sense) solution :) (If I'm counting it right, both my solution and yours perform four checks each, including both the boolean check and the nothingness ones, while Reid Barton's does only three.)

Comment: I think yours does five: three binds, a guard, and a case.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're right -- using `guard` in this way effectively duplicates the boolean check.

Answer (score 5):

I guess this will somehow not be satisfactory for your real codebase, but how about

```
  (record :: Maybe Record) <- getRecord
  case record of
     Just (Record { validate = Just True, mobile = m }) -> do
        sendSMS m
     _ -> return ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Have your validation return both whether it's valid and the value of the record:

```
someFunction = do
  mrecord <- getRecord
  let hasValidated = do
        record <- mrecord
        valid <- validated record
        return (valid, record)
  case hasValidated of
     Just (True, record) -> do
        sendSMS (mobile record)
     _ -> return ()
```

Once you've made this change, you can refactor a fair bit:

```
someFunction = do
  mrecord <- getRecord
  traverse_ (sendSMS . mobile) $ do
    record <- mrecord
    True <- validated record
    return record
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not make validation

```
validate :: Monad m => Record -> MaybeT m Record
getRecord :: Monad m => MaybeT m Record

someFunction = fromMaybe () <$> runMaybeT (getRecord >>= validate >>= doStuff)
```

such that validate returns record if validated or `Nothing` when non-valid.